# How to add today's date in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am trying to check if a submitted date is equal to today's date using C#.  How can I check to see if the submitted date equals today's date. Here is what I have so far:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select distinct UserID, cast (DT_Submitted as date)DT_Submitted from myTable where UserID = @UserID", sqlcon);
DataTable dtSETS = new DataTable();
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", (tempUser));
da.Fill(dtSETS);

if (dtSETS.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataRow dtSETS_row = dtSETS.Rows[0];           
    DateTime dtSubmitted = dtSETS_row.Field<DateTime>("DT_Submitted");

    if (dtSubmitted == todays date )
    {
        //do something..
    }
}
```

Comment: Today's date in which time zone? "Today" means different things in different places.

Comment: Have you tried to google "todays date C#"?

Comment: Could be irrelevant, but if you only need to process submitted dates equal to today, why don't you add another criteria in your WHERE clause ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.Today` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if your `DT_Submitted` datetime has a midnight as a time part.

Even if not, you can use it's [`.Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) to compare with it.

```
if (dtSubmitted.Date == DateTime.Today)
{
    //do something..
}
```

But of course as Jon says, *Today* can mean different things than depends on where you are.

Comment: the date value i am getting from my table is like this: 2015-03-18 so i can't compare it with datetime value.  How can i compare it without the time value?  thanks

Comment: @moe, Note that the code in this answer uses the Date-property of the dtSubmitted DateTime object. You should be able to compare that with DateTime.Today.

Comment: @moe Since you called it with `Field<DateTime>`, I suspect your `DT_Submitted` column typed with `date`, `datetime` or `datetime2` column types. Don't worry, these column types are mapped with CLR's `DateTime` type and all `DateTime` values have date and time part. If you debug your `dtSubmitted` variable after you get it with `dtSETS_row.Field<DateTime>("DT_Submitted")` part, you will see it's date and time parts. That means it **is** a `DateTime` and you can use it's `Date` property as well.

Comment: when i debug i see this: dtSubmitted.Date = 2015-03-19 10:33:16.983 and DateTime.Now.Date is not the same as dtSubmitted date value.  please help

Comment: @moe No, `dtSubmitted.Date` should seen as `2015-03-19 00:00:00.000` not `2015-03-19 10:33:16.983`. This `Date` property set time part to midnight. That's why you need to check it as `dtSubmitted.Date == DateTime.Today` for example.

Comment: @moe, are you sure you are checking the correct properties? Here is what I get when I debug both the local variable (http://imgur.com/2ixH9he) and the static proerperty from DateTime.Today (http://imgur.com/aRrSOWa)

Answer (score 0):

You could just try this:

```
if(dtSubmitted.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Beware if you use either `DateTime.Now.Date` or `DateTime.Today` the corresponding values contains a time part.

For instance for today 3/19/2015 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: thanks but as you can see in my sql, i am casting the date value as date so the value i am getting is actually like this: 2015-03-18.  So how can i compare if one has datetime value and the other has only the date portion only?

Answer (score 0):

```
dtSubmitted.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
```